# Spring Batch: get list of defined jobs at runtime

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

Is it possible to get a list of defined jobs in Spring Batch at runtime without using db? Maybe it's possible to get this metadata from `jobRepository` bean or some similar object?

Comment: What do you mean by "defined jobs"?  Jobs in the local application context? Jobs in the job repository?  Some other definition?

Comment: I mean all jobs which I defined in my local application context

Comment: You can do that with something as simple as `context.getBeanNamesForType(Job.class)`.

Comment: It will not work, as job is not a regular bean and you can find it in context or via getBean(jobName)

Comment: Sure it is.  A Job is no different than any other bean in your context.

Comment: Hm, you right, I thought that spring-batch job is something like resource..
And when use this context.getBeanNamesForType(Job.class) I'm always getting empty array. But the problem is that I used another context. My fault. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is possible to retrieve the list of all job names using [`JobExplorer.getJobNames()`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/JobExplorer.html#getJobNames--).

You first have to define the `jobExplorer` bean using [`JobExplorerFactoryBean`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/core/explore/support/JobExplorerFactoryBean.html):

```
<bean id="jobExplorer" class="org.springframework.batch.core.explore.support.JobExplorerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
</bean>
```

and then you can inject this bean when you need it.

Comment: It works, but it use db. Is there way to find it without db?

Answer (score 3):

To list jobs defined as beans, you can just let the spring context inject them for you all the bean types of type `Job` into a list as below:

```
@Autowired
private List<? extends Job> jobs;

..
//You can then launch you job given a name.
```

Comment: Works for me, the @Autowired ListableJobLocator jobLocator; jobLocator.getJobNames(); suggestion from another answer did not return any job in my case.

Answer (score 2):

I use these code to list and execute jobs

```
private String jobName = "";
    private JobLauncher jobLauncher = null;
    private String selectedJob;
    private String statusJob = "Exit Status : ";
    private Job job;
    ApplicationContext context;
    private String[] lstJobs;

    /**
     * Execute
     */
    public ExecuteJobBean() {
        this.context = ApplicationContextProvider.getApplicationContext();
        this.lstJobs = context.getBeanNamesForType(Job.class);


        if (jobLauncher == null)
            jobLauncher = (JobLauncher) context.getBean("jobLauncher");
    }

    /**
     * Execute
     */
    public void executeJob() {

        setJob((Job) context.getBean(this.selectedJob));

        try {
            statusJob = "Exit Status : ";
            JobParameters jobParameters = new JobParametersBuilder().addLong("time", System.currentTimeMillis()).toJobParameters();
            JobExecution execution = jobLauncher.run(getJob(), jobParameters);
            this.statusJob = execution.getStatus() + ", ";
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            this.statusJob = "Error, " + e.getMessage();
        }
        this.statusJob += " Done!!";
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative strategy to get list of job names that are configured as beans one can use the ListableJobLocator.

```
@Autowired
ListableJobLocator jobLocator;

....

jobLocator.getJobNames();
```

This does not require a job repository.